# Return BLOB stream without reading in memory

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a blob storage

```cs
class Blob{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public byte[] Content { get; set; }
}
```

I want to return stream of `Content`. For now I read whole data and return `MemoryStream`.

**Current code**

```cs
public async Task<Stream> GetOrNullAsync(BlobProviderGetArgs args)
{
    var blob = await DatabaseBlobRepository.FindAsync(id);

    if (blob == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    return new MemoryStream(blob.Content);
}
```

As you see, firstly I read whole data then return `MemoryStream`.

It is not problem for small objects but consider that there is a 1gb Blob, it will be problem.

Is there any way to improve it like return `Stream` through EfCore?
Can you suggest best practises for this issue.

Comment: does this help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sqlclient-streaming-support

Comment: After some searching I found that https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/6234. It is not available for it.

Comment: I am having same issue, did you figure this out? what you tried?